# How can the terminal in Jupyter automatically run bash instead of sh

Tags: jupyter

I love the terminal feature and works very well for our use case where I would like students to do some work directly from a terminal so they experience that environment.  The shell that launches automatically is sh and does not pick up all of my bash defaults.  I can type "bash" and everything works perfectly.  How can I make "bash" the default?

Comment: I guess it should pick up your default shell. What shell do you get if you open a normal terminal?

Comment: With ssh, I am getting bash.  I should track it down.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? If so how?

Answer (score 24):

Jupyter uses the environment variable `$SHELL` to decide which shell to launch. If you are running jupyter using init then this will be set to dash on Ubuntu systems. My solution is to `export SHELL=/bin/bash` in the script that launches jupyter.

Comment: I have set this in /etc/profile and /etc/environment and yet I still have the same problem, any ideas why?

Comment: One can also launch jupyter with `SHELL=/bin/bash jupyter-lab ...`

Answer (score 8):

You can add this to your jupyter_notebook_config.py

```
c.NotebookApp.terminado_settings = {'shell_command': ['/bin/bash']}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason, do you know of any ideas why?

Comment: You may need to use `c.ServerApp.terminado_settings` instead of `NotebookApp` in newer versions.

Comment: With either `c.NotebookApp.terminado_settings` or `c.ServerApp.terminado_settings`, I'm getting the following error with Posit Workbench: `rstudio-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'`

Answer (score 7):

I have tried the ultimate way of switching system-wide SHELL environment variable by adding the following line to the file **/etc/environment**:

```
    SHELL=/bin/bash
```

This works on Ubuntu environment. Every now and then, the SHELL variable always points to **/bin/bash** instead of **/bin/sh** in Terminal after a reboot.

Also, setting up CRON job to launch **jupyter notebook** at system startup triggered the same issue on **jupyter notebook's** Terminal.

It turns out that I need to include variable setting and sourcing statements for Bash init file like **~/.bashrc** in CRON job statement as follows via the command **$ crontab -e**  :

```
    @reboot source /home/USERNAME/.bashrc && \
            export SHELL=/bin/bash && \
            /SOMEWHERE/jupyter notebook --port=8888
```

In this way, I can log in the Ubuntu server via a remote web browser (http://server-ip-address:8888/) with opening **jupyter notebook's Terminal** default to Bash as same as local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Since Jupyter server [2.0.0](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/releases/tag/v2.0.0), `--ServerApp.terminado_settings="shell_command=['/bin/bash']"` should work.

For `jupyterlab==3.6`, I can confirm myself it works:

```
jupyter lab --ServerApp.terminado_settings="shell_command=['/bin/bash']"
```

See also [Juptyer Server PR  #949](https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/pull/949).

Answer (score -9):

With Jupyter running on Ubuntu 15.10, the Jupyter shell will default into /bin/sh which is a symlink to /bin/dash.

```
rm /bin/sh
ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

That fix got Jupyter terminal booting into bash for me.