# How do I change default shell when using zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s helm chart

Tags: bash, jupyter, jupyterhub

The default shell when deploying https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s is `sh`.
The problem is that the arrows don't work.

e.g. when you want to see list through cmd history or you want to fix a typo in the command.
You get `^[[A` when pressing arrow up.

This can be fixed by changing the shell from `sh` to `bash`.

Sadly I can't use the answers from [How can the terminal in Jupyter automatically run bash instead of sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467098/how-can-the-terminal-in-jupyter-automatically-run-bash-instead-of-sh) when using this helm chart.

Answer (score 0):

add this to [singleuser](https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/stable/resources/reference.html#singleuser) config:

```
singleuser:
  extraEnv:
    SHELL: "/bin/bash"
```